# spring boot starter validation simply not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-validator

### Problem:

I need to validate some json inputs and outputs in my Spring API, I'm trying to use spring boot starter validation (Already know that is not into spring-boot-starter-web, so I added it manually) but it never throws the exception when something is bad based on the validations in the DTO class (MethodArgumentNotValidException)

Complete project can be fonud on [github](https://github.com/sebasvil20/spring-validating)

What I've tried:

1. I tried adding this 3 dependencies:

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
       <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
       <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   And is not working, I'm able to send incorrect values without throwing the exception

   P.S. I already know that spring boot starter validation is not into spring-boot-starter-web, so I added it manually

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```

   If I try to use spring-boot-starter-validation without the validation-api (from javax) it directly says that some methods do not exists (Like @Valid or @Max or @Min)
2. Already Rebuild project
3. Already clean maven repository and installed again

### What I have:

**DTOs**:

```java
import lombok.*;


import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StudentDTO {
    @NotEmpty(message = "Username cant be empty")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50, message = "Minimum 2 letters, max 50")
    String studentName;
    String message;
    Double averageScore;
    List<@Valid SubjectDTO> subjects;
}
```

```java
import lombok.*;

import javax.validation.constraints.*;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SubjectDTO {
   @NotEmpty(message = "Subject name cant be empty")
   @Size(max = 30, message = "Max 30 letters")
   @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Z](\\p{L}||\\s)+", message = "Name should start with capital letter")
   String name;
   @Max(value = 10, message = "Max grade is 10.0")
   @Min(value = 0, message = "Min grade is 0.0")
   Double score;
}
```

```java
import lombok.*;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ErrorDTO {
   private String name;
   private String description;
}
```

**Rest controller**:

```java
import com.practicastesting.diploma.dto.StudentDTO;
import com.practicastesting.diploma.service.IObtenerDiplomaService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
public class ObtenerDiplomaController {
   @Autowired
   IObtenerDiplomaService service;

   @PostMapping("/analyzeScores")
   public ResponseEntity<StudentDTO> analyzeScores(@RequestBody @Valid StudentDTO rq) {
       return new ResponseEntity<StudentDTO>(service.analyzeScores(rq), HttpStatus.OK);
   }
}
```

**Exception controller**:

```java
import com.practicastesting.diploma.dto.ErrorDTO;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

import java.util.Objects;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {
   @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
   @ResponseBody
   @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
   protected ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> handleValidationExceptions(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {
       ErrorDTO error = new ErrorDTO("MethodArgumentNotValidException", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getBindingResult().getFieldError()).getDefaultMessage());
       return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
   }

}
```

**Well, with that, when I try to send some json like:**

```json
{
   "studentName": "a",
   "subjects": 
       [
           {
               "name": "Math",
               "score": 115
           },
           {
               "name": "Whatever",
               "score": 7
           },
           {
               "name": "Chemistry",
               "score": 6
           }
       ]
}
```

It should give me an error, telling me the message of each of the validations that are defined into the DTO, but is not giving me any error or exception, it just save it into the repository, and working normally.

### More details:

I'm using:

- Spring boot 2.5.4
- Java 11

my pom.xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.4</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.practicastesting</groupId>
   <artifactId>diploma</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>diploma</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <properties>
       <java.version>11</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
           <version>2.4.2</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
           <scope>runtime</scope>
           <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
           <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
           <optional>true</optional>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
           <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
           <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.0</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <excludes>
                       <exclude>
                           <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                           <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                       </exclude>
                   </excludes>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

**If u need more details just ask, ill give them all**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello @Sebastián Villegas, I downloaded your project from GitHub and proved it with the request that you added above and the program is doing the corresponding validation (result that I obtained bellow):

```
{
    "name": "MethodArgumentNotValidException",
    "description": "Minimum 2 letters, max 50"
}
```

Rebuild your project. If you are using IntelliJ IDEA as your IDE, in the menu go to ***Build -> Rebuild Project***

Comment: I dont really know what happened, but I rebooted my pc and now it works... (Im not kidding) Maybe something about cache or kinda. Ty for the answer tho!

Comment: If you are using `Intellij` these thing can happens. Try `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart` when something odd happens. Cheers!

Comment: samething hapened to me. i spent hours in investing . i had to just restart my eclipse

Answer (score 0):

**Don't need any extra dependency if you added `spring-boot-starter-web` the dependency in the pom.xml file.**

Create an exception class, annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> processUnmergeException(final MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {

    List<String> list = ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().stream()
            .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Almost done, make sure `@valid` annotation is added to the controller method, like

```
public ResponseEntity<ReservationResponseDto> create(@Valid @RequestBody ReservationCreateDto reservationCreateDto) {
    log.info("Creating a reservation by consumerId:{} in:{}",
            reservationCreateDto.getConsumerId(),
            reservationCreateDto.getReservationStartAt());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(reservationService.save(reservationCreateDto), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Your DTO class should be like this:

```
public class ReservationCreateDto {

-------
-------
@NotNull(message = "staff id can't be null")
@Min(value = 1, message = "staff id can't equal or less than 0")
private long staffId;
-------
-------
```

Output: you get the output looks like this:

```
[
"staff id can't be less than or equal 0"
]
```